# FindByIdAsync returns null user object, dotnet core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have problem loading user object using FindByIdAsync (FindByIdEmailAsync, FindByNameAsync also doesn't work in this specific case). The FindByIdAsync returns null.

IdentityController.cs

```
public class IdentityController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private readonly IIdentityService identity;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public IdentityController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                              IIdentityService identity,
                              RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.identity = identity;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> Roles(string id)
    {
        var user = await this.userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

        var u = this.userManager.GetUserId(User);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }      
     ....
```

The user is in database:
[user in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNn8S.png) and User id is passed to the controller action:
[Debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C07Fg.png)

Have tried some sort of playground with new standard VS2017 ASP.NET Core MVC Template and added only FindByIdAsync on About and it WORKS.

Thanks

Comment: Where is PascalCase `User` coming from in this line `this.userManager.GetUserId(User)`? Should it be `user` instead?

Comment: User cumming from ControllerBase. But this line is not related to the issue, is just for check can be UserId get this way. The problem was that parameter id is incorrect wrapped with { } due to my bug in Razor template. Thanks to Dave Cousineau seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your images, your `id` string is wrapped in `{` and `}` symbols, yet that is not the string that is in the database. I also notice that the value you get back from `GetUserId` is not wrapped in braces. Either parse out the braces from `id`, or use the value of `u`, or pass the right value to `Roles`.

Ex:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Roles(string id)
{
    if (id.Length > 0 && id[0] == '{')
       id = id.Substring(1, id.Length - 2);

    var user = await this.userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

    var u = this.userManager.GetUserId(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }      
 ....
```